# Sending Bytes properly to client

Tags: python-3.x, byte, binary-data

In Python, I am trying to build a simple server/client application that sends video bytes to the client.

I have been trying to figure this out for months.

The server is listening to a connection, and is receiving this much data every second, length of 1316

for example:
`data = sock_reciever.recv(16000000)`

If I print `data`, I get this:

```
b'G\x05\x14\x1e\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x14\x1f\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x14\x10\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x14\x11\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x14\x12\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x14\x13\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffG\x05\x17\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

As this comes in, I can send it back out via `sock_sender.sendto(data, (SENDMCAST_GRP, SENDMCAST_PORT))`, and watch the video in VLC player.

Ultimately, I want to take this data and send it to the client through the socket via `conn.send(data)`.

---

However, on the client side, I believe data is coming in in the wrong order.

I've compared the data between server and client and it appears to be the same, but it builds up on the client side, which might be causing some sort of overflow.

On the client side, I take the data coming in with `data = sock_reciever.recv(16000000)` and send it back out via `sock_sender.sendto(data, (SENDMCAST_GRP, SENDMCAST_PORT))`.

But I do not get the same results on the client side, as on the server side.

How do I add headers to this data to ensure it arrives to the client in sequential order?

If possible, please explain this to me like you would explain what oxygen is to a fish.

### Which Sockets I Am Using

I am trying to use TCP sockets between server and client. I thought using a stream socket would be more reliable, but I might be wrong, the only reason being that I would like to do a reverse connection, so that the client connects to the server and then receives data.

I am also using `sock_sender.sendto(data, (SENDMCAST_GRP, SENDMCAST_PORT))` just to relay the incoming data on the client side, it is not the actual connection between server and client.

The socket used for the communication between server/client
is called `sock_client`.

This is the server-side code:

```
sock_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# recieves connection from client
conn, address = sock_client.accept()

# sends data to client
conn.send(data)
```

Client Side is set up like so:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

data = s.recv(2400000)
```

Then the data is just relayed back out for use with other applications via `sock_sender.sendto(data, (SENDMCAST_GRP, SENDMCAST_PORT))`.

I need to ensure the data between the client/server socket connection is accurate and complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it a little bit. The video can be sent in the form of bytes with the aid of struct. It is part of the python standard library string services.
It interprets strings as packed binary data and performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings. This is helpful handling binary data in files, socket network connections and other sources. In server.py, the frame matrix is pickled dump as a string in variable a and then used struct.pack to add a reference payloadsize (for the string in a). The payload_size is attached using + to the a and then .sendall sends the whole frame. To simply explain it, lets suppose our frame is just 3x3 matrix:

frame=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

a = pickle.dumps(frame)

The pickled form of frame is shown below as a string:

b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\
x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy
\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00
\x00\x00

Here payload_size: len(a) is 193 and its string representation in a 4 byte 'L' format is b'\xc1\x00\x00\x00'. 
Then, message = struct.pack("L", len(a))+a

b'\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\
x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03K\x03\x86q\x06cnumpy
\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00
\x00\x00

And now the message also contains the payload_size infront of the data. The len(message) = 197.
In client.py the s.recv(4096) means at the most 4096 bytes will be received through a blocking call.
The data is appended to the string in 4096 bytes per packet. The rest of the part is quite obvious.
For reference working versions of server.py and client.py are below. First run the server.py and then in another command window run client.py. The transmitted and received frames will be displayed. You can increase the number of maximum bytes. I hope this solves your problem!

server.py

```
    import socket,cv2,pickle
    import struct
    serversocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 9999
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
    serversocket.listen(5)

    while True:
        clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

        print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
        if clientsocket:
            vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            while(vid.isOpened()):
                img, frame = vid.read()
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                print(frame)
                a = pickle.dumps(frame)
                message =struct.pack("L", len(a))+a
                clientsocket.sendall(message)
                cv2.imshow('Transmitted',frame)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord("q"):
                    clientsocket.close()
```

client.py

```
    import socket,cv2,pickle
    import struct
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 9999
    s.connect((host, port))
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") 
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            packet= s.recv(4096)
            if not packet: break
            data += packet
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]
        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += s.recv(4096)
        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]
        frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
        cv2.imshow('Received',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
    s.close()
```